# Checking advertised routes - BGP

Tags: cisco, bgp, juniper-junos

For **IOS-XE** and **Junos**, I wanted to know the command that displays the routes advertised by BGP to neighbors. On IOS-XR, this command is 'show bgp advertised'.

I know on XE, per neighbor based advertised routes can be checked. But I want advertised routes to all the neighbors combined.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE: Confirmed with Cisco TAC - for Cisco IOS-XE, there is no such command to view routes to ALL the neighbors. It can only be per neighbor based.**

Comment: It would help if we knew a little more about why you need the routes and what you want to do with this information

Comment: @MikePennington We wanted to provide support in our product to import BGP RIB for all routes advertised to all neighbors using show command (SNMP to device, run show command, grab the data), so the customers can view it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Junos, the command is "show route advertising-protocol bgp 'neighbor'".

According to the XE [command reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_bgp/command/iproute_bgp-xe-3se-3850-cr-book/iproute_bgp-xe-3se-3850-cr-book_chapter_0100.html#wp3502759178):

show ip bgp neighbors 'neighbor' advertised-routes

Comment: Thanks. Checking into the Junos device, I found the command you mentioned and not any particular command for ALL neighbors together. So I guess like IOS-XE, Junos also displays only per neighbor basis.